# automate input procedure to a binary file

Tags: shell, ant, input, automated-tests

I have a binary file on UNIX, which when executed asks the user for inputs. The inputs to this binary file are given manually.

I want to automate the procedure, since I know the inputs already. I can't modify the binary file. How can I do this? Is this possible via `shell script` or even with `ant` targets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple input redirection may work:

```
$ binaryFile <<EOF
input line 1
input line 2
input line 3
EOF
```

If you need something more complex, look into the [expect](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm) package.